# What's the difference between a bijection and an isomorphism?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I don't understand what the difference is between a bijection and an isomorphism.  They seem to both just be a invertible mapping.

Is the set of all bijections a subset of isomorphisms?  Or vice versa?  What is the difference and can you show me an example of one that is not the other?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, in my opinion. Indeed, I had seen that "duplicate" question before the close votes and specifically did not vote close. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are talking just about sets, with no structure, the two concepts are identical. Usually the term "isomorphism" is used when there is some additional structure on the set. For example, if the sets are groups, then an isomorphism is a bijection that preserves the operation in the groups: $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$. As another example, if the sets are vector spaces, then an isomorphism is a bijection that preserves vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: OK.  So an example of a bijection that's not an isomorphism is the function $(x,y) \mapsto (x+1,y)$ on $\Bbb R^2$.  It's clearly invertible, but doesn't preserve vector addition.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Another example would be the map from $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}:n\mapsto n+1$. This is a bijection, but does not preserve addition.

Comment: @user200571: Right, it's not an isomorphism of groups, nor of vector spaces — it doesn't respect *algebraic* structure. However, it does preserve distances, so it's an isomorphism of metric spaces — it respects *geometric* structure.

Comment: Note that an isomorphism is not always a bijection. For example, an isomorphism in the category of topological spaces up to homotopy equivalence can be very far from it, as can be an isomorphism in the category of metric spaces up to a quasi-isometry. Not to mention some more abstract categories, where morphisms are not even (equivalence classes of) functions.

Comment: @tomasz I thought that usually _isomorphism_ is defined as _bijective homomorphism_? Obviously you can use the same word for different things, so are the isomorphisms you mention isomorphisms in the same sense as in the answer?

Comment: In short, a bijection (or -jection) is a kind of function on sets. An isomorphism (or -morphism) is a kind of function that is structure preserving. Or rather one term is in the language of set theory, the other is in category theory. Underlying all isomorphisms is some bijection, but a bijection doesn't necessarily preserve structure in the category you care about. If your category is Sets, then they're the same.

Comment: @JiK: The question is general. In general, an isomorphism in a category is a morphism which has a two-sided inverse. If morphisms are functions, then isomorphisms are obviously bijections, but that is not always the case. Moreover, even if morphisms are functions, in general not every bijective morphism is an isomorphism (because the inverse may fail to be a morphism), for instance the mapping $x\mapsto x^p$ gives a bijective morphism from the affine line into itself (in the category of algebraic varieties over field of characteristic $p$), but it is not an automorphism if it is not identity.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "vice versa." An isomorphism is a *structure-preserving* bijection. The specific meaning of "structure" will vary, depending on the context.

Comment: OK.  Can you give an example of a bijection that's not an isomorphism, then?

Comment: Consider the map $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ given by $n\mapsto-n.$ This is readily a bijection, but not a ring isomorphism. (Here's where the "depending on context" part comes into play, because it *is*, for example, a *group* isomorphism.)

Comment: @user200571 Any enumeration of the rationals, i.e. any bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, will not preserve the usual order on the rationals. There will always be some $q_1<q_2$ with $f(q_1)>f(q_2)$.

Comment: @CameronBuie By "enumeration" I mean "bijection with $\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: @Ian: Wow! That was completely my bad! I'm not sure how I managed to misinterpret that.... :-/

Comment: Actually, I have my inequalities reversed; I think there is a way to not have the disagreement above. The other way ($q_1 > q_2$ but $f(q_1) < f(q_2)$) will always happen, however: choose $q_1$ such that $f(q_1)=1$.

Comment: @Ian: Both ways will always happen. That is, if $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb N$ is a bijection, then there will always be some $q_1<q_2$ such that $f(q_1)>f(q_2),$ and there will always be some $r_1>r_2$ such that $f(r_1)<f(r_2).$ Can you prove it?

Comment: Ah, of course: for the other direction, we can take the intersection of the rationals with a closed interval with rational endpoints. Then the image is infinite, so it has no maximal element, but the original set has a maximal element.

Comment: I think that works. The easier way to go is to compose $f$ with the map that takes $q_1\mapsto q_2,$ $q_2\mapsto q_1,$ and $q\mapsto q$ for all $q\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{q_1,q_2\}.$

Comment: @Ian: Wow! We were not smart about this one at all. Put $r_1:=q_2$ and $r_2:=q_1.$ I have no idea what my composition was to accomplish. Your approach might still work, but neither approach is necessary. :-P

Answer (score 2):

As Cameron says, an isomorphism is a structure-preserving bijection, like a group isomorphism, which is a bijection that preserves the group structure. Or ring isomorphisms. Or algebra isomorphisms. Or module isomorphisms. Or ...

Homeomorphisms are the mappings that preserve the topological properties (more precisely, they are isomorphisms in the category of topological spaces). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Notes) gives a counterexample to the statement that every bijection is an isomorphism:

> Consider for instance the function $f: [0, 2π) → S^1$ (the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$) defined by $f(φ) = (\cos(φ), \sin(φ))$. This function is bijective and continuous, but not a homeomorphism ($S^1$ is compact but $[0, 2π)$ is not). The function $f^{−1}$ is not continuous at the point $(1, 0)$, because although $f^{−1}$ maps $(1, 0)$ to $0$, any neighbourhood of this point also includes points that the function maps close to $1$, but the points it maps to numbers in between lie outside the neighbourhood.